# Using Python's subprocess.call to kill firefox process

Tags: python, linux, firefox

I am trying to kill any firefox processes running on my system as part of a python script, using the script below:

```
    if subprocess.call( [ "killall -9 firefox-bin" ] ) is not 0:
        self._logger.debug( 'Firefox cleanup - FAILURE!' )
    else:
        self._logger.debug( 'Firefox cleanup - SUCCESS!' )
```

I am encountering the following error as shown below, however 'killall -9 firefox-bin' works whenever I use it directly in the terminal without any errors.

```
       Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "./pythonfile", line 109, in __runMethod
 if subprocess.call( [ "killall -9 firefox-bin" ] ) is not 0:
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 478, in call
 p = Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 639, in __init__
 errread, errwrite)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
 raise child_exception
 OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something or should I be trying to use a different python module altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate the arguments when using `subprocess.call`:

```
if subprocess.call( [ "killall", "-9", "firefox-bin" ] ) > 0:
    self._logger.debug( 'Firefox cleanup - FAILURE!' )
else:
    self._logger.debug( 'Firefox cleanup - SUCCESS!' )
```

`call()` normally does not treat your command like the shell does, and it won't parse it out into the separate arguments. See [frequently used arguments](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for the full explanation.

If you must rely on shell parsing of your command, set the `shell` keyword argument to `True`:

```
if subprocess.call( "killall -9 firefox-bin", shell=True ) > 0:
    self._logger.debug( 'Firefox cleanup - FAILURE!' )
else:
    self._logger.debug( 'Firefox cleanup - SUCCESS!' )
```

Note that I changed your test to `> 0` to be clearer about the possible return values. The `is` test happens to work for small integers due to an implementation detail in the Python interpreter, but is *not* the correct way to test for integer equality.

Comment: As a side note, you should probably encourage OP to use `... != 0` instead of `is not 0`, and in the second case, (`shell = True`), you no longer need a list.  Passing a string is just fine.

Comment: @mgilson: best is to use `> 0` actually.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was more worried about the fact that `is` works with small integers only as a Cpython implementation detail.  But, I suppose if you want to go the extra mile and actually think about what return codes are legal in an unsigned 1byte integer, I suppose that's reasonable. :)

Comment: Yeah, added a note about that. I was focusing on the issue at hand first.

Comment: thank you the 2nd suggestion using shell=True worked for me :)